# Powershell: shorter way to execute command with many filenames?

Tags: powershell, command-line, command

Instead of typing this long command on the command line:

```
python babynames.py baby1990.html baby1992.html baby1994.html ... baby2008.html
```

Is there a shorter way to type like this for years from 1990 to 2008 with a increment of 2?

Comment: I think you can build a string, then run `. $yourstring` to execute it as a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

powershell way :

```
$cmd="babynames.py"
(1998..2008)|%{
    if ($_ % 2 -eq 0){
        $cmd=$cmd+" baby"+$_+".html"
    }
}
start-process python.exe $cmd
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, do a For loop.

```
$Cmd = "python babynames.py"
For($a=1990;$a -le 2008;$($a++;$a++)){
    $cmd = "$cmd baby$a.html"
}
& $cmd
```

Comment: Interesting.  Never thought `$cmd = "$cmd baby$a.html"` works like `$cmd += " baby$a.html"`

Comment: Actually, when I run `& $cmd` I got the following error: `The term 'python babynames.py baby1990.html baby1992.html baby1994.html baby1996.html baby1998.html baby2000.html
baby2002.html baby2004.html baby2006.html baby2008.html' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program.` Even though the python command works directly on the command line.

Comment: @vxs8122 try to specify the full path to python.exe

Answer (score 3):

Another version:

```
$f = 0..9 | % { "baby$(2 * $_ + 1990).html" }
& python.exe babynames.py $f
```

or in one line:

```
& python.exe babynames.py (0..9 | % { "baby$(2 * $_ + 1990).html" })
```